# JavaScript find "newest" version of a string

Tags: javascript, string

This is probably something really easy, but I can't think of any good solution here:

I have an array of strings:

```
let array = ['House1', 'House2', 'House3', 'Block1', 'Block2', 'BlockSpecial1'];
```

In time this array will change, but at any point I want to able to reduce that array to just the "newest" versions of the strings (based on the ending numbers, they may become 2- or 3-digit at some point), so what I want in the end would be:

```
['House3', 'Block2', 'BlockSpecial1']
```

Comment: The question you ask can be answered. It might also be wise to consider if this data structure of an array of strings with a terminal number is the optimal data structure for your needs. Even an array of objects where the object include the string and a separate number might be easier, or it could be some queue structure depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this actually very cleanly by creating a `Map`.

```js
const array = ['House1', 'House2', 'House3', 'Block1', 'Block2', 'BlockSpecial1'];

const re = /^([^]+?)(\d+)$/;
const result = [...new Map(array.map(s => re.exec(s).slice(1)))]
                  .map(a => a.join(""));

console.log(result);
```

Here's the rundown...

In a `.map()` over the original array, divide each string between its text and number using a regex, and return an array that has only the captured parts.

Have the `.map()` result become the argument to the `Map` constructor. This creates the map with each first member of the sub array as each key, and the second as the value.

Because a `Map` must have unique keys, you only get the last key produced for each redundant key, which will also have the highest number.

Then convert that map to its remaining key/value entries, and join them back into a string.

---

Here's the same code from above, but breaking it into parts so that we can log each step.

```js
const array = ['House1', 'House2', 'House3', 'Block1', 'Block2', 'BlockSpecial1'];

const re = /^([^]+?)(\d+)$/;
const keysVals = array.map(s => re.exec(s).slice(1));

console.log("original split:", keysVals);

const m = new Map(keysVals);
const mapKeysVals = [...m];

console.log("mapped keys vals", mapKeysVals);

const result = mapKeysVals.map(a => a.join(""));

console.log("result", result);
```

Answer (score 3):

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array to an object with the string as key, and the version as value. To get the string and version, you can use [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), and [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring). Then use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), and [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to combine it back to strings:

```js
const array = ['House1', 'House2', 'House3', 'Block1', 'Block2', 'BlockSpecial1'];

const result = Object.entries(array.reduce((r, s) => {
    const [, str, version] = s.match(/([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)/);

    r[str] = (r[str] || 0) > version ? r[str] : version; // or r[str] = version if the versions are always in the right order

    return r;
  }, Object.create(null)))
  .map(([k, v]) => k + v);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let tmp, name;
let array = ['House1', 'House2', 'House3', 'Block1', 'Block2', 'BlockSpecial1'];
let newest = array.sort((a, b) => b.match(/\d+$/)[0] - a.match(/\d+$/)[0]).sort().reverse()
.reduce((newArr, item) => (name = item.match(/.+[^\d]+/)[0], name != tmp && (newArr.push(item), tmp = name), newArr), []);

console.log(newest) //[ 'House3', 'BlockSpecial1', 'Block2' ]
```